# Conjugacy classes of a triple

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, nilpotent-orbits

In [the paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00927879208824339) " THE COMPONENT GROUPS OF NILPOTENTS IN EXCEPTIONAL SIMPLE REAL LIE ALGEBRAS" by D. King I am unable to proof the lemma 3.7 which is omitted there.
The lemma is following:
Let $\mathfrak g $ be a exceptional and $R$ be a regular subgroup ( normalized by a maximal torus) of $G$. Let ($x_1,e_1,f_1$) and ($x_2,e_2,f_2$) be semi-regular triples in Lie($R$).(Semi-regular means centralizer of $(x_1,e_1,f_1)$ in $R$ is equal to the center of $R$) Now if ($x_1,e_1,f_1$) and ($x_2,e_2,f_2$)  are conjugate in $G$ then they are conjugate in $R$.

It is also not clear to me that why he assume $\mathfrak g$ to be exceptional Lie algebra. Is it not true for classical Lie algebra.

Any reference for the proof of this lemma is also useful.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this area of literature in which classical results for complex Lie algebras are adapted to real cases, but Don King was a student of Kostant (whose methods are being adapted here).   Probably it's most efficient to contact D. King directly at Northeastern: ...@neu.edu     In any case, I'd expect the lemma itself to be true for all semisimple Lie algebras, though the paper focuses just on exceptional types.